# Unable to install Ubuntu on

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, intel-graphics

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a **Live USB**, but was unable to get into the live environment when I selected **Try Ubuntu without installing** option.

Then I tried again by selecting **Install Ubuntu** option at the **Grub screen**. This time I got the initial screen, but it appeared broken. So, I couldn't continue.

The hardware is an `Ivy Bridge` Intel processor, `Intel Pentium G2020`, the motherboard is `Gigabyte H61M-S1`, with 2GB RAM. The available hardware details of the machine, generated by `CPU-Z` application in windows, can be found at this [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7198064/) Could not get into the live CD environment, so had to use `CPU-Z`.

Is it a graphics, issue with the on-board graphics; if so, any way to overcome it? How can I install Ubuntu 12.04, in this machine?

[image: Broken screen display]

Comment: Try to make bootable USB once again, this time using **Startup Disk Creator**. **Startup Disk Creator** is available in Ubuntu only so you may have to consult some one using Ubuntu. Or you can also use **Unetbootin** but **Startup Disk Creator** is recommended..

Comment: you can use the alternate installer see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/442308/72216. It is (I think) the same question.

Comment: do you have nvidia graphics card. for my old pc with nvidia grpahics card, installation failed because of conflict with gnome based environment. so i use linux mint mate on it

Comment: @SauravKumar, I had used the bootable usb created using **Startup Disk Creator**, and that is when this error had occured.

Comment: @aveemashfaq, No there is no nvidia graphics card, the pc has only onboard intel graphics.

Answer (score 0):

try installing from pendrive using unetbootin

u can download it here http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net

if u have ubuntu 12.04 iso file you can use Diskimage option in unetbootin, u can see how to install here

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#install

i hope that works

Comment: I had used the live bootable USB created using Ubuntu's `Startup disk creator` application. Is creating with `unetbootin` and different?

Comment: yes unetbootin has a different interface at boot-time it worked fine always for me, its effective and easy to use too give it a try

Comment: Ok, I'll check and tell.